# How to send transform.position and transform.rotation values?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, multiplayer

This is for a multilayer game where i need to send the postion and rotation values for the server and get it back from there again.Google only allows sending through bytes. This is what i am trying.

```
float aa;
float bb;
float cc;


byte[] xx =new byte[5];
byte[] yy =new byte[5];
byte[] zz =new byte[5];

Update()
{
aa=transform.postion.x;
bb=transform.postion.y;
cc = transform.postion.z;

xx = System.BitConverter.GetBytes (aa);
yy = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(bb);
zz = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(cc);

PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime..SendMessageToAll(false,xx);
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.SendMessageToAll(false,yy);
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.SendMessageToAll(false,zz);

}
```

If i send it this way, how will i know what data is being sent?

```
public void OnRealTimeMessageReceived(bool isReliable, string senderId, byte[] data) {
 if(data[0]==(byte)'R' )
 {
  //Convert back the data
  float xyz = System.BitConverter.ToSingle(data,0);
 }
 }
```

So my question is how to send the position value and also rotation in Google Play Multiplayer through Unity3D? How are you guys doing it? This method is not giving any compile errors but i have a strong feeling this is not the right way and there are better ways than this.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to use [State Synchronization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/net-StateSynchronization.html) in your example. However, be aware that working on multiplayer is always a game of trade offs, and you must be very sure about what you want to achieve. Networking code of large-scale RTS is completely different from a fast-paced FPS.

Comment: I am using Google Play Multiplayer services.